# Why am i able to do this implicit substitution in this definite integral without changing the bounds?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was told that I was able to do the following when solving a definite integral:

$$\int_2^3 \frac{1}{4x-1}dx$$ $$\int_2^3 \left(\frac{1}{4x-1}\cdot \frac{d(4x-1)}{dx}\right) dx$$
Note that the second expression should be divided by 4...

Why am I simply able to ignore that the term I am integrating with respect to and just divide by $dx$? Is there something I’m missing or failing to realise here?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! You can use TeX math symbols to express mathematical formulas. [See this link to find appropriate symbols you needed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula)

Answer (score 1):

In the manipulation$$\int_2^3\frac{1}{4x-1}dx=\int_2^3\frac{1}{4x-1}\underbrace{\frac{\frac{d(4x-1)}{dx}}{\frac{d(4x-1)}{dx}}}_1dx\stackrel{u=4x-1}{=}\int_{x=2,\,u=7}^{x=3,\,u=11}\frac{1}{u}\frac{\frac{du}{dx}}{4}dx=\int_7^{11}\frac{1}{u}\frac{1}{4}du,$$the first $=$ inserts a factor of $1$ into the integrand, while the second rewrites that factor's numerator and denominator as $\frac{du}{dx}$ and $4$ respectively. The last step uses the chain rule $\frac{du}{dx}dx=du$. In your question, you make the introduced numerator explicit in a display-line expression, while mentioning the denominator below it. Your question seems to be why you can write the numerator as a derivative. Well, we're only inserting a factor of $1$ into the integrand, so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that

$$ \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(x)\,d\,g(x)=\int_a^b f(x)g^\prime(x)\,dx $$

So

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_2^3\frac{1}{4x-1}\,dx&=&\frac{1}{4}\int_2^3\frac{1}{4x-1}\cdot4\,dx\\
&=&\frac{1}{4}\int_2^3\frac{1}{4x-1}(4x-1)^\prime\,dx\\
&=&\frac{1}{4}\int_7^{11}\frac{1}{4x-1}\,d\,(4x-1)\\
&=&\frac{1}{4}\ln|4x-1|\Big|_{4x-1=7}^{4x-1=11}\\
&=&\frac{1}{4}\ln|x|\Big|_7^{11}
\end{eqnarray}

etc.

Comment: @J.G.  Thanks for the correction.